# Why can't I add this directory to git?

Tags: git

```
$ git add . ; git add *; git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

My folder is in there, but I can't add it.

Comment: i dont have a .gitignore

Comment: Can you add the output of `git ls-files -i` to your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By any chance, is the directory blank? You can't add directories to git.

Comment: Why did you mark this as accepted if the folder has stuff in it? It doesn't sound like your question has been answered.

Comment: yeah - i have the same question

Comment: Is the stuff in the folder hidden so that your git process can't see it?

Comment: It has to be the .gitignore file. Check it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is quite old now and the answer has been accepted but I had a similar problem where I couldn't add a directory.

In my case the problem was that I didn't have permission to access the directory.  I changed the permissions and then I was able to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Does your folder have hidden files? This may cause the git process not to see the files, and treat the folder as though it were empty

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and the reason was an added line in the github `.gitignore` file that in my case doesn't tracked `.exe` files.